# How to use a list in functions outside main?

Tags: c#, list, function

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lazo
{
    class Program
    {
        List<string> L = new List<string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //List<string> L = new List<string>();
            L.Add("L");
            L.Add("A");
            L.Add("Z");
            L.Add("O");

            izbrisiElement("test");
        }

        static void izbrisiElement(string element_brisi)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < L.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (L[i] == element_brisi)
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the list created in main in other functions outside main. I have tried inside main and outside main, but none works. I'm not exactly sure where my mistake is. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: _"none works. I'm not exactly sure where my mistake is"_ You should mention the problem/error next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Main` method is `static`, it means it doesn't belong to any *instance*, but you are declaring your list as an instance field.So when you access it in a method it means you are trying to access the member of the current instance in other words: `this.L`, but `this` doesn't exist in the `static` context.

You need to make it `static`:

```
static List<string> L = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare it as static:

```
static List<string> L = new List<string>();
```

in order to be used from your static methods.